# Is this the right code for a pop up window?

Tags: debugging

I wanted this code to pop up a window when the password is correct and when the password isn't correct I wanted to make it go to google.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script language="Javascript">
<!--hide
var password;
var pass1="12345";
<a href="https://www.google.com/?safe=active&ssui=on"
target="_blank" onclick="preventProp(event)">Google</a>
function preventProp(e){
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to open this link ?")){
    return true;
}
password=prompt("Enter Password To View Zapazzi","");
if(password!==pass1)
window.confirm("Incorrect Password, click ok to go to Google");
else
{
alert("Correct Password, click ok to go to Zapazzi");
window.location="https://sites.google.com/cusdk8.org/zapazzi/home";
}
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just know that this provides absolutely no security whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

here is what you have to do

1. remove the `<a href="https://www.google.com/?safe=active&ssui=on"
   target="_blank" onclick="preventProp(event)">Google</a>` from `<script> </script>`
2. change script type to `<script type="text/javascript">`
3. change the `<a href="...>` to button because when it is a link tag it firstly does its job of redirecting before listening to the event so I used button

here is my clean code that is working

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
  <HTML>
    <head>

    </head>
 <body>
      <button onclick="preventProp(event)">Google</button>

      <script type="text/javascript">

          var password;
          var pass1="12345";

       function preventProp(e){
          if(confirm("Are you sure you want to open this link ?")){
            return true;
           }  
        password=prompt("Enter Password To View Zapazzi","");
     if(password !== pass1)
    window.confirm("Incorrect Password, click ok to go to Google");
  else{
    alert("Correct Password, click ok to go to Zapazzi");
    window.location="https://sites.google.com/cusdk8.org/zapazzi/home";
       }
      }

       </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` is not necessary in HTML5, though.